# Jasperreports NulPointerException producing PDF/A files

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, itext, pdfa

I'm using this code to produce a PDF, all works well.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File(reportname));
JRDataSource ds = ... a datasource
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, d.getHashMap(), ds);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, output_path + "p4.pdf");
```

When I try to produce a pdf compliant pdfa1b I obtains this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA1Checker.checkPdfObject(PdfA1Checker.java:323)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAChecker.checkPdfAConformance(PdfAChecker.java:208)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAConformanceImp.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfAConformanceImp.java:71)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3426)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3422)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(PdfDictionary.java:137)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray.toPdf(PdfArray.java:175)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(PdfDictionary.java:149)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:420)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:398)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:334)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:829)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1311)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.close(PdfAWriter.java:336)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:886)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:830)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:519)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:505)
    at ga.jr.run.RunMe.main(RunMe.java:45)
```

this is a portion of my jasper file

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.conformance" value="pdfa1b"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.icc.profile.path" value="Z:\\Produzione\\Development\\TEMPLATE\\sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc"/>
```

No exception if I remove the net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.conformance (or set it to "none"), but the file is not a PDF/A

what is wrong?
thanks

EDIT: I'm using iText 5.5.3 (same issue using itext 5.5.0) and Jasperreports 6.0.0

EDIT: tested using AdobeRGB1998.icc and sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc, ISOnewspaper26v4_gr.icc and ISOnewspaper26v4.icc, eciRGB_v2.icc and ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc (found in my PDFCreator installation directory) same exception

Comment: Which iText version is used in your installation? In certain versions there had been issues like this which meanwhile have been fixed... And is your ICC path correct? At first glance it could be an ICC issue.

Comment: I'm using iText 5.5.3 (same issue using itext 5.5.0) and Jasperreports 6.0.0
Path to ICC file is correct, different error if I remove the icc file

Comment: maybe a different icc file can resolve?
but same result using AdobeRGB1998.icc

Comment: Please try. the exception occurs in the context of the output intent / colorspace analysiy.

Comment: Already tested using AdobeRGB1998.icc and sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc, same exception

Comment: same result using ISOnewspaper26v4_gr.icc

Comment: tested also with ISOnewspaper26v4.icc

Comment: I added the iText tag because the error pops up in iText. Maybe Bruno has an idea. I won't have the time to reproduce the situation today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. I reverted to version 5.6.1 and all works ok.

Today is 17/12/2014 and I'm waiting for a Jasperreports version above 6.0.0.

Bug documented at
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3988

> When i try to create a PDF/A document with version 6.0.0 of
>   JasperReports Library i always get a NullPointerException at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA1Checker.checkPdfObject, line no.
>   332.
>
> Exactly the same report works fine with 5.6.1 (using iText 2.1.7js2)
>   exported as PDF/A.
>
> If we take a look at the source of PdfA1Checker, we see (starting at
>   line 327):
>
> PdfObject iccProfileStream =
>   dictionary.get(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE); String inputColorSpace =
>   ""; if (iccProfileStream != null) { ICC_Profile icc_profile =
>   writer.getColorProfile(); // Always returns null try { inputColorSpace
>   = new String(icc_profile.getData(), 16, 4, "US-ASCII"); // NPE!!! on access to icc_profile } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { throw
>   new ExceptionConverter(e); } }
>
> I did a debug session and found out that writer.getColorProfile()
>   *always* returns null. This seems to be the case because JRPdfExporter does NOT initialize it. So, i guess, this issue is a side effect of
>   the upgrade to iText 5.5.0. (I think PdfWriter.setOutputIntents must
>   be called to set the icc_profile correctly...)
>
> Hope this helps, fixing this.
>
> Regards, Michael
>
> v6.0.0 JRPdfExporter

Comment: You may consider to update your post, 1/2 solution in 6.1 reverting to old iText library. I have fixed the link to the issue but can't edit your post on this issue.